# Linux kernel "half configured"

Tags: debian, kernel, package-management

I've been running Debian Wheezy for over a year with no problems until a week ago.  For no obvious reason, the system has suddenly decided that the Linux kernel is only half-configured, and none of the fixes I've found on-line have worked.  As a result, `apt` tries to remedy it every time updates are performed, and fails.

#### Details

**Symptom**

Any time updates are run, `apt` will, at some point, try to fix the kernel, fail, and the update process will terminate with error advice, and then a message that the system is up-to-date.

Any updating activity by `apt` ends with the following:

```
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.2.0-4-amd64 /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.2.0-4-amd64 /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64
E: /usr/sbin/update-initramfs.orig.initramfs-tools - command not found
E: On Debian based systems, update-initramfs from initramfs-tools
E: can be installed with:
E:   apt-get install initramfs-tools
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64.postinst line 696.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**The Kernel**

Virtually the same problem was described in a [question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/647171/cannot-apt-upgrade-due-to-kernel-package-problems).  The accepted answer pointed to a problem with the `dpkg` status file.  The status entry for **`linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64`** said it was half configured.

As a first step, I tried this:

```
administrator@Kwheezy:~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64 is broken or not fully installed
```

Reinstalling didn't help, so that points to broken.

The Ask Ubuntu solution was to delete the entry from the `dpkg` status file and then reinstall.  In my case, that didn't work either.  When the process was done, the `dpkg` status file had replaced the entry with another that still said it was half configured, and the system behavior was the same.

**Apt Output**

Focusing on the error messages in the `apt` output.  The errors always begin with:

```
/usr/sbin/update-initramfs.orig.initramfs-tools - command not found
```

Sure enough, that file doesn't exist.  The helpful message advises that it can be installed by installing **`initramfs-tools`**.  That was already installed, but I reinstalled it.  It turns out that `apt` was already doing that on its own.  All of the error messages following the guidance to install **`initramfs-tools`** is generated by that installation attempt, which never results in **`/usr/sbin/update-initramfs.orig.initramfs-tools`** being installed.

**Summary**

- I have the latest available Linux kernel from the Wheezy repository.  It is a good copy, all dependencies are met, and there are no reports of other users having problems with it.
- The system reports that it is not fully configured.  I've found no way to either get it configured or get the system to stop thinking that it's not.

Comment: Can you provide the contents of `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools`?  It should be trying to load `/usr/sbin/update-initramfs`, not `/usr/sbin/update-initramfs.orig.initramfs-tools`.  If the file `/usr/sbin/update-initramfs` exists, try `sudo ln -s /usr/sbin/update-initramfs{,.orig.initramfs-tools}` and then running your update again.

Comment: @Deltik, I'm not a programmer, but it does look like what it's loading is /usr/sbin/update-initramfs.  Still want the contents of /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools?  I generated the symlink and ran the update.  It produced a new set of errors (looks like the link may not match what it expects). Where's a good place to upload files?

Comment: This is more complicated than I thought.  Would you like to [discuss this in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41021/fixer1234s-kernel-update-issue)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Resolution

```
sudo apt-get remove live-tools
sudo apt-get install --reinstall initramfs-tools
sudo apt-get install -f
```

---

### Explanation

After getting a better picture of fixer1234's system [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4102fixer1234s-kernel-update-issue1/), I determined that the installed package `live-tools` was conflicting with `initramfs-tools`.

When `live-tools` is installed, it overrides `/usr/sbin/update-initramfs` with its own script and puts the original in `/usr/sbin/update-initramfs.orig.initramfs-tools`.

`live-tools` has some sanity checks that detect if it's on a live system.  If it's not on a live system and is on an installed system, it tries to run `/usr/sbin/update-initramfs.orig.initramfs-tools`, which is the correct script to update the initramfs.

In fixer1234's system, `/usr/sbin/update-initramfs.orig.initramfs-tools` had been deleted.

Since the system is an installed system, `live-tools` is probably unnecessary, which is why I recommended its removal.

Here's how each step proposed in the "Resolution" section above works:

#### `sudo apt-get remove live-tools`

Removing `live-tools` will attempt to restore `/usr/sbin/update-initramfs.orig.initramfs-tools` back to `/usr/sbin/update-initramfs`, but since `/usr/sbin/update-initramfs.orig.initramfs-tools` doesn't exist, there will be an error.

`live-tools` will still be removed, and this is what matters.

We are still missing `/usr/sbin/update-initramfs`.

#### `sudo apt-get install --reinstall initramfs-tools`

To restore `/usr/sbin/update-initramfs`, we reinstall the package that provides that file.  Namely, `initramfs-tools`.

#### `sudo apt-get install -f`

Your kernel installation was incomplete due to the mishap with `live-tools` and `initramfs-tools`, so to complete the installation and resolve all package issues, this last step is needed.

Now, you should have a fully functioning Debian system.

(By the way, these steps theoretically work on Debian 8, Ubuntu 12.04, Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 15.10, Ubuntu 16.04, and Ubuntu 16.10.)

Comment: Guess we'll never know what caused this.  But I'm reading the explanation, and it sounds plausible, but I still think Deltik used some magic in the solution.  :-)  Fantastic job!  Thanks.